# Open problems in Cellular Automata field

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computational-complexity, automata, computational-mathematics, cellular-automata

here there is a link on Wolfram about [20 open problems of CA theory](https://www.stephenwolfram.com/publications/cellular-automata-complexity/pdfs/problems-theory-cellular-automata.pdf).

Has anyone of them been solved or tested?
I'm searching for literature.